# Python decimal places value fixed

Tags: python

I'm trying to have always 2 decimal places in a float number, e.g:

```
3.28329482394283104923804 -> 3.28
3.0 -> 3.00
3 -> 3.00
```

with `round(x,2)`, but the problem is that the second case `(3.0 -> 3.00)` is returning `3.0` instead of `3.00`. What can I do?

I have the values and I'm creating a string like this:

```
final = "The number is " + str(number)
```

Comment: Is that only for display ?

Comment: print the value, yes

Comment: _I have the values and I'm creating a string like this_ Why not use proper string formatting?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to round off the number to obtain a string to display, you can do,

**Try this:**

`print("{:.2f}".format(3.28329482394283104923804))` outputs `3.28`

`print("{:.2f}".format(3.0))` outputs `3.00`

`print("{:.2f}".format(3))` outputs `3.00`

OR using the fstrings in python,

`print(f'{3.28329482394283104923804:.2f}')` outputs `3.28`

`print(f'{3.0:.2f}')` outputs `3.00`

`print(f'{3:.2f}')` outputs `3.00`

---

UPDATE (as you asked in comments):

```
final = f"The number is {number:.2f}"
```

Comment: can I do it in a different way? can you adapt this to the changes I've made?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this notation, can you do it in a different way? 
I have this line:
    result +=  j + '=' + str(number) + ','
How can I do it?

Comment: @LokoLokoNini You can't do this without using format strings. The other way is `final = "The number is {:.2f}".format(number)`